# Laravel 8, Eloquent mutator does not called at all

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mutators

I created a mutator in model class as follows:

```
public function setFileDataAttribute($value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            $value = [];
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

The corresponding field is : **file_data**.
Catsts and fillables are also set:

```
protected $casts = [
        "created_at" => "datetime:Y-m-d H:i",
        "file_data" => "array",
    ];

protected $attributes = [
     "file_data" => [],
    ];
```

I have really tried everything, but it is simply not called (I have dd-ed it - nothing)
Anyone, any idea?

---

Update:
The class is (simplified):

```
class XXX extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        "name",
        "cost_type",
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
       
        "file_data" => "array",
    ];

    protected $attributes = [
        "file_data" => [],
    ];

    public function setFileDataAttribute($value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            $value = [];
        }

        return $value;
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Also mention what you are trying to do with `file_data` and on what situation it's not called mutators?

Comment: you are not showing where you are trying to set that attribute

Comment: Thanks guys. When I create a new record in database with the model create, passing the request object, that is the phase when the mutator is supposed to be called. As far as I know the mutator runs when creating new model with Model::create().

Comment: The mutator is supposed to be called:

 XXX::create(
            $request->only(
                "name",
                "file_data",
            ),
        );

Comment: Mutators only work if property contains any value. Otherwise it's ignored. You can not trigger a mutator if your property is null.

Comment: Luciano, thanks. Yes, this could be the reason. I should check if it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something here;
You need to actually set the value, using `$this` keyword. For example:

```
public function setFileDataAttribute($value)
{
  if (is_null($value)) {
     $value = [];
  }

  $this->attributes['file_data'] = $value;
}
```

Or better:

```
$this->attributes['file_data'] = is_null($value) ? [] : $value;
```

There are differences between accessor and mutators. If you want to use accessor, you can use `get` keyword instead of `set` and your approach is just fine, however, if you want to mutate it when you are inserting or updating the database, you need to assign it to the attribute.

**Accessor:** An accessor transforms an Eloquent attribute value when it is accessed.

**Mutator:** A mutator transforms an Eloquent attribute value when it is set.

More at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Akmal, I am trying again, I will see if it works or not.